# Did Rothschild say this famous quote? If yes, what did he mean by it?

Tags: quotes, banking

> "Give me control of a nation's money and I care not who makes it's laws" — [Mayer Amschel Bauer Rothschild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer_Amschel_Rothschild)

This prominent international banker is commonly quoted this. First, did he actually say it? Second, what was its context (when and where was he and what other things did he say shortly before or after this) if we know? Finally, seeing as how this is likely his most notable quote, did he ever reflect on it at a later time shedding some light on it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The actual quote which is attributed to [Mayer Amschel Rothschild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer_Amschel_Rothschild) is:

> Permit me to issue and control the money of a nation, and I care not who makes its laws!

A number of sources ([such as this one](http://modernhistoryproject.org/mhp?Article=FinalWarning&C=1.4#Arrows)) claim that this statement was made in 1838 (which would have been a difficult feat as he would have been dead for 26 years by then). [Wikiquote claims](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Money#Misattributed) that there is no way to verify by whom, when or why it was made. It notes:

> No primary source for this is known and the earliest attribution to him known is 1935 (Money Creators, Gertrude M. Coogan). Before that, "Let us control the money of a nation, and we care not who makes its laws" was said to be a "maxim" of the House of Rothschilds, or, even more vaguely, of the "money lenders of the Old World".

It is adapted from another well known quote:

> Let me make the songs of a nation, and I care not who makes its laws.

This is in turn attributed to the Scot, [Andrew Fletcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Fletcher_%28politician%29#Main_works):

> In An Account of a Conversation he made his well-known remark "I knew a very wise man so much of Sir Christopher's sentiment, that he believed **if a man were permitted to make all the ballads, he need not care who should make the laws of a nation.**"

Comment: iow it's contributed to Rothschild most likely by conspiracy theorists wanting to paint a black system of "evil bankers controlling the world's governments" :)

Comment: I'm a little confused at your first source. It seems that there was more than one Rothschild with the names Meyer and Amschel. Maybe I have confused the two (or more). However, wikiquotes indicates that the earliest cite is 1935. What is the evidence that Mr. Daniel in that work was making a play on that old English proverb and not simply stating a commonly believed notion? +1 so far.

Comment: @fredsbend In the Wikipedia article that you cite in your Question, his eldest son is named as [Amschel Mayer Rothschild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amschel_Mayer_von_Rothschild).

Comment: @fredsbend I've clarified the identity of the Rothschild with a link. As for the 1935 source, we simply don't know. It is suggested that if Mayer Amschel did make such a statement, then he was simply adapting an earlier saying. However, it is not certainly known if he actually made such a statement at all as the earliest record of it being made was written ~123 years after his death. Presumably Mr. Daniel did not cite a reliable source which makes the matter questionable in terms of its authenticity.

Comment: Near the top of the page in the example you cite are birth/death dates which then conflict with the birth/death dates for the quote.  See http://modernhistoryproject.org/mhp?Article=FinalWarning&C=1.4#Arrows  So at a minimum this example is in question with itself.

Comment: @jwenting  - That's only because there are "evil bankers controlling the worlds governments." Do you know who prints the money for the United States? The "Federal Reserve Bank". Do you know that they are a private corporation that lends the money they print to the US Govt at an interest rate? Do you know why Libya was turned into an ISIS playground? Do you know why Syria is at war?It all has to do with bankers...Read this before you speak of this https://www.amazon.com/Creature-Jekyll-Island-Federal-Reserve/dp/0912986395/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_img_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=5N60FYQWJ6FQJTPYBTN1

Comment: @DanB the very assumption they're evil is the problem... Yes, the Federal Reserve is a private corporation (something many people don't know and most who do know find weird). And no, the world's problems aren't all due to bankers, you're just regurgitating the blame game here.

Comment: @jwenting He only used the word 'evil' because you used it first. And I think it is plain to see that their are 'banking forces' behind, or at least influencing, a lot of political events such as wars and other foreign policy affairs. Fact is you are generalizing people that don't agree with the banking system as 'conspiracy theorists'. You are attacking their person instead of their arguments. Them attributing a quote to the wrong person is a good argument. Them 'being conspiracy theorists' is not.

Comment: @StijndeWitt ... Actually, I used the word evil intentionally... They are evil to their core (at least the ones making the decisions). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1Qt6a-vaNM Check out this long (but brilliant and very thoroughly researched documentary (JFK to 9/11) - It's all about the money... and the evil... Scary stuff... research the Bilderberg Group and their annual meetings if you really want to be in the know...

Comment: @jwenting Actually, I used the word evil intentionally... They are evil to their core (at least the ones making the decisions). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1Qt6a-vaNM Check out this long (but brilliant and very thoroughly researched documentary (JFK to 9/11) - It's all about the money... and the evil... Scary stuff... research the Bilderberg Group and their annual meetings if you really want to be in the know... (Reposted to allow both you and Mr. Witt to view)

Answer (score 21):

The saying is apocryphal and was originated by the populist author T. Cushing Daniel, a Washington-based lobbyist and lawyer, in his testimony before the U.S. Congress in 1911 in hearings on House Resolution 314 (whether financiers were restricting trade by domination of the money supply). This is what Daniel said:

> William Pitt made this statement: "Let the American people go into
>   their debt-funding schemes and banking systems, and from that hour
>   their boasted independence will be a mere phantom." He realized the
>   maxim that Rothschilds laid down as fundamental: "Let us control the
>   money of a country and we care not who makes its laws."

It is true that the Rothschilds had "maxims" and these were published by London weeklies in the 1890s. All of these maxims were homey things like "Be sure you are right, then go forward." Cushing simply invented the imaginary "control the money" maxim for the purposes of his books and testimony.

The original Rothschilds were very religious, modest people. Its hard to imagine Nathan R. or his brothers as having said such an arrogant thing and it conflicts with what is known about his personality. Long after Nathan R. was dead, during the period 1890-1910, which was a period of anti-trust and anti-wealth agitation in the United States many writers made up all kinds of stories to portray the Rothschilds and other "barons" according to their stereotypes of rich, arrogant puppet masters. These stereotypes often did not resemble the actual people.

Concerning the phraseology and idea that Daniel expressed, this was not original to him, but, as you might imagine, was adapted from the works of others. In this case the phrase appears to have come from a short paper on the History of New York State published in 1892 by Welland Hendricks, a school principal. This is what Hendricks wrote:

> Our Dutch forefathers who seemed to care little whether the flag of
>   England or of Holland floated over the weak fort of New Amsterdam so
>   long as their trade was uninterrupted have bequeathed their spirit to
>   our keen-sighted non-voting business men of to-day, and all along the
>   motto of our leading citizens has seemed to be — let us make the money
>   of the nation and we care not who makes its laws.

Daniel completely perverted the original sense of the sentence to his own purpose. Hendricks was borrowing the phrase as well. In 1890, a meddlying clergyman named Wilbur Crafts, who tried to get all kinds of moralistic laws passed in New York, wrote a tract promoting the banning of work on Sunday containing the paragraph:

> Massachusetts took upon herself the appointment of Boston's Police
>   Commissioners, and so of her police. The lawless had been saying for
>   years, "Let us appoint the city's police and we care not who makes its
>   laws."

The actual origin of the printed phrase dates back to the 17th century Scottish Parliamentarian, Andrew Fletcher:

> I said I knew a very wise man so much of Sir Christopher's sentiment,
>   that he believed if a man were permitted to make all the ballads he
>   need not care who should make the laws of a nation, and we find that
>   most of the ancient legislators thought that they could not well
>   reform the manners of any city without the help of a lyric, and
>   sometimes of a dramatic poet.
>
> **-- An ACCOUNT of A CONVERSATION concerning A RIGHT REGULATION of GOVERNMENTS For the common Good of Mankind: In A LETTER to the Marquiss of Montrose , the Earls of Rothes, Roxburg and Haddington, From London the first of December, 1703'.**

Now, of whom is Fletcher speaking? Who is the "very wise man"? It is, of course, [Sir Phillip Sydney (1554-1586)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Sidney), the English poet who came to completely dominate the court of Queen Elizabeth even though he was only in his 20s. Sydney is the one who originated the phrase "Let me make the ballads of a nation, and I care not who makes its laws."

Comment: "Fletcher of Saltoun quotes from one of his friends ... that if a person had the making of the ballads of a nation, he need not much care who had the making of its laws." ([Source](https://memory.loc.gov/service/gdc/scd0001/2004/20040416002ap/20040416002ap.pdf)) Fletcher lived 1655 to 1716; Sidney from 1554 to 1586, so your "wise man" attribution fits far better than a "friend". Do you have a direct source for Sidney's quote?

Answer (score 4):

What he (probably) meant by it (who can say for sure now?) is that of all the possible means a government has to control and influence its people, the issueing of money is the most powerful one. Even more powerful than law.

By creating new money, the government can decrease the value of the existing money in circulation, thereby lowering the buying power of those holding it. In turn it can use the created money to buy assets on the free market. It's not fair competition.

This quote is often used in (political) statements against [fiat money](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money). They reason that by inflating the money supply, governments are actually stealing the wealth from their people without them (directly) noticing it. It is much easier to just create new money than to raise taxes. Tax revolts were quite common back in the old days, but inflation revolts? None would be the wiser until it was too late. "Read my lips, I will not raise taxes.". He says nothing about national debt, eh?

The United States, before they became independent of England, had issues with their (forced) use of the English pound, a currency which they did not control. The US constitution actually spends quite some words on trying to prevent US money from ever becoming fiat. Money should belong to the people was the founding fathers' opinion, and not to the head of state. [Thomas Jefferson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Jefferson) has even been quoted as saying that

> I believe that banking institutions are more dangerous to our liberties than standing armies.

So there you have it. Money is more powerful and dangerous than both laws and standing armies.

Comment: Can you show us some sources with your answer?

Comment: I agree with you, but you answered the question from an economist's standpoint, not an historian's. If you take a peek at the selected answer you will see that the earliest source we could find for this quote was over 100 years after Rothschild's death. Unless someone finds something else, I actually have no reason to believe that the quote originated with Rothschild.

Comment: True. Sorry I'm a StackOverflow regular, not a history.stackexchange regular. I guess it shows. In my defense though I like to point out that I was answering the actual question being asked: "What did Rothschild actually mean by this famous quote?". This is why my answer does not focus on the origin of the quote but the meaning. Why would he compare the control of the nation's money supply with it's laws? Because control over the money supply is a tremendous political force. Also, I believed that the origin was already very well covered in the other answers.